# How to make floating action bar center bottom

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

Can you help me how to make floating action bar like this, and fixed position on center bottom.

I use ConstraintLayout

[image: img]

Comment: can you please share your xml layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a linear layout with horizontal orientation inside a constraint layout. Constraint the linear layout to the bottom, the end, and the start of the constraint layout.

Here's a simple example.

[image: Layout]

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/floating_action_bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/a"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/b"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/x"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to place a view at the bottom centre of your screen in constraint layout you need to add the following to your view:

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
```

Here's an example:
[image: layout]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/floatingActionButton2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:srcCompat="@android:color/holo_orange_dark" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/floatingActionButton3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:srcCompat="@android:color/holo_orange_dark" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/floatingActionButton4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/floatingActionButton2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:srcCompat="@android:color/holo_orange_dark" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/floatingActionButton5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/floatingActionButton3"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:srcCompat="@android:color/holo_orange_dark" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/floatingActionButton4"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:srcCompat="@android:color/holo_orange_dark" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The views at the bottom are chained together and all of them constraint to the bottom of the screen, with the first one to the left constraint to the left start of the parent and the last one to the right constraint to the right end of the parent.

Answer (score 0):

for bottom Center in constraintlaout set this constraints to floating button
and if wants to add multiple floating buttons the add all this FloatingActionButton in
LinearLayout orientation="horizontal" and add this constraints to LinearLayout
and in the pic this are not FloatingActionButton they are Views so You can add as you want

```
  app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the horizontal bias attribute.

I guess you have something like this `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.76"`

Simply remove it or set it to `0.5`